# Spring Boot and Mongo - findById only works with ObjectID and not Id of String

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot GraphQL service which reads from Mongo.

I've noticed that if my MongoDB document ID has `ObjectID` e.g. `"_id": ObjectID("5e5605150")` I'm able to get results from doing `myRepository.findById(myId)`.

However if that id is just a string like `"_id": "5e5605150"` then `findById` returns nothing.

The repository looks like this:

```
@Repository
interface MyRepository : MongoRepository<Song, String>
```

And that Song looks like this:

```
@Document(collection = Song.COLLECTION)
data class Song(
    @Id
    val id: String,

    val title: String
) {
    companion object {
        const val COLLECTION: String = "song"
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Spring Data MongoDB reference on mapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html) - the `_id` field is treated specially. If it's a String or BigInteger type, it will automatically be converted to/from an `ObjectId`. MongoDB supports plain strings for the special `_id` field though, so if you're inserting documents that don't go through Spring Data (or inserting documents as a raw JSON string for the MongoDB driver to insert) then MongoDB won't automatically convert strings to `ObjectId` - it will store them as strings.

So, if you insert the document `{"_id": "5e5605150"}` into your DB, the Spring Data MongoDB mapper won't be able to find it, because it will be searching by `ObjectId` only.

Comment: Ah, ok got it. So the main point for me to remember here is `inserting documents that don't go through Spring Data` or not will cause that automatic conversion to `ObjectId`